# DRF Serializer get/post/delete working but "put" failing

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to implement a basic CRUD API for the "Item" model. It is working for the most part, but I am running into what seems like a minor problem with the put method. I have run it through the debugger several times so I know that the serializer is at least partially functional, but it does not appear that the "update" serializer method is not successfully updating my database. Here is the view:

```
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        item = Item.objects.get(id=request.data["id"])
        serializer = ItemSerializer(item, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is the serializer:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Item Serializer
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = "__all__"
        lookup_field = "id"

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get("name", instance.name)
        instance.description = validated_data.get(
            "description", instance.description)
        instance.price = validated_data.get("price", instance.price)
        instance.discount = validated_data.get("discount", instance.discount)
        instance.quantity = validated_data.get("quantity", instance.quantity)
        instance.category = validated_data.get("category", instance.category)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Here is the test that I am using to debug the problem (unsuccessfully, so far):

```
    def test_update_item(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(self.team_member)
        self.team_member.is_staff = True
        res = self.client.put(
            ITEMS_API,
            {
                "id": self.hat.id,
                "name": "Bucket Hat",
                "description": "Exclusive bucket hat"
            },
        )

        self.assertEquals(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEquals(hat.name, "Bucket Hat")
```

Comment: is there a reason for you to override the update and the put methods ? seems like you are trying to do exactly what they already do

Comment: And can you add any errors or exceptions you have?